# Should I always prefer member variables to parameters method when it makes sense?

Tags: java, oop, jdbc

Put value as a field makes sense only if this one represents some object's state.

I wonder if this "rule" should be avoid in certain case.

Here an example, suppose this class :

```
public class DbCar {

    private ResultSet rs;

    public DbMapper(ResultSet rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    public Car buildObject(){
        //.....does some mappings, then returns the builded car ....
    }
}
```

So we see that ResultSet is stored as a member variable and it makes sense since every DbMapper like DbCar manipulates a retrieved ResultSet from JDBC query.

We would have a caller looking like as follows:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   items.add(new DbCar(rs)).buildObject();
}
```

But imagine that the current query returned 15000 records.

To put it in a nutshell => 15000 instances of DbCar objects were created.

So my question is : **Is the garbage collector efficient enough so that I shouldn't worry about this huge number of instances ?**

Of course, to avoid all these instances, we can refactor the code as follows:

```
public class DbCar {

    public Car buildObject(ResultSet rs) {
        //.....does some mappings, then returns the builded car ....
    }
}
```

In this case, a single instance of DbCar (in the current thread and in the current method) would be created, and the caller looking like as follows:

```
DbCar dbCar = new DbCar();
while (rs.next()) {
   items.add(dbCar.buildObject(rs));
}
```

So, which solution should I choose ? Trust on garbage collector with a more elegant code or coding like a more procedural coding-style with local parameter method ?

In order to make choice harder, imagine that the DbCar class divides its "build" method into elegant small methods, each one dedicated to a specific responsibility like for instance :

"buildEngine", "buildDoors" etc... In case of local parameter choice, I would have to pass ResultSet into all these methods... boring and redondant isn't it ?

Comment: I would pass the ResultSet as a parameter, hands down.

Comment: In the 2nd case, unless you have a very good reason for creating a `DbCar` object, you should just make `buildObject` static.

Comment: @trutheality Imagine (and in mostly case), DbCar inheriting of DbObject. This one listing some useful methods to ease manipulation of resultSet. So if it was static, we couldn't profit from this superclass.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. How does having a buildObject() method avoid having to create the 15000 objects? And what does that have to do with whether the ResulSet is a member variable? (hitch it should never be).

Comment: @EJP Of course in both cases there will be 15000 created Car objects but I don't focus on these objects but on the object who instanciated them(dbCar). So in the first case, 15000 DbCar are created however in the second case, only one instance is enough.

Comment: @Skip Head read my comment just above :)

Comment: @Mik378 you can still inherit static methods. Objects should (almost) never be used as containers that hold a bunch of methods that can otherwise be static. For a method to be meaningfully non-static, it needs to somehow be dependent on the current state of the object it belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not constitute a problem for the GC but it all boils down to your application requirements.

In a previous project, I was involved in developing a very big "near real time" application that runs on a Solaris server (requires 10GB of RAM to start) the application is creating something like 150000 DTO objects every 4 seconds or so. This has no impact on the GC at first glance but after some working hours, the users started complaining about the software loosing data coming out of the hardware. We spent a long night investigating the problem and we finally found out that the GC was taking full CPU to clean up the unused objects which made the application look like it hanged for a second or so (trust me, a second of data loss costs more than 1000$)

Answer (score 4):

2nd is better. 15000 objects is nothing for the garbage collector, but hanging on to the resultset object is not recommended. #2 is better for that reason

Comment: +1 - hanging on to a transient stateful object like a result set is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I would trust that garbage collector can do this nicely, and choose the most clear implementation. If you find later that this causes a performance problem, you can refactor then. You should always do the more clean implementation, unless you have a proven reason not to (like a profiler showing you that this is a bottleneck and you should lose some clarity to make it faster).

I would be surprised if GC couldn't handle this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular problem it's mostly a matter of functional design. One normally should not worry about garbage collector when designing a program. If you have to think in GC, i would think you are working on application with non functional requirements for using a very few memory or you are optimizing a very big architecture. It's that your case?

Out there you can find pattern for implementing templates like this. I'm refering to Spring JDBC Template for example:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

Comment: I work in an investment bank so database are huge. Thus, though a lot of allocated memory, there's often a potential risk to get unexpected behaviours if the code isn't enough optimized.

Comment: I also work mantaining a big bank architecture. We work with Spring ORM, with its JDBCTemplate wich it's very flexible letting you map resultsets to primitive types or objects.  If you don't have spring available, i would suggest you your second approach with corresponds to Spring Template ORM Pattern wich is a pattern widely used. Cheers.